# SPSS OMS extract to dataset on regressions that have already been run

Tags: output, regression, spss

My team keeps sending the output files of regressions and we extract them into excel. Specifically the model summary and the Coefficients tables.

Is there a way that I can get OMS to extract the tables from existing output files? Or will I have to run the regressions again?

Comment: I don't have a version available to me at the moment to test, but you might be able to extract the elements [via Python](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2015/04/13/extracting-items-from-spss-tables-using-python/). But the answer is no to using OMS for the already printed output. Also you can export the entire workbook to excel, but if you re-run the regressions with OMS you have more control on how they are exported.

Comment: Thank you Andy for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMS works only from the Statistics backend at the time the output is generated.  You can't use it on output.  However, you can use OUTPUT EXPORT to create Excel files from Viewer objects.  The problem with this in some scenarios is that OUTPUT EXPORT run from syntax doesn't give you control over which tables are exported, although you can select them manually in the Viewer and use OUTPUT EXPORT to export all those selected.

If that is an issue for you, you can use the SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT extension command with a custom function included with the command to select the tables to export based on the OMS table types.  Here are some examples.

Export a custom table from the most recent command to a new Excel file.
SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT TABLES
/IF SUBTYPE="'Custom Table'" PROCESS=PRECEDING
/CUSTOM   FUNCTION="customoutputfunctions.excelexport(file='c:/temp/extest.xls')".

Export all the custom tables in the Viewer to separate sheets named table1,  table2, ...
SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT TABLES
/IF SUBTYPE="'Custom Table'" PROCESS=ALL
/CUSTOM FUNCTION="customoutputfunctions.excelexport(file='c:/temp/extest.xls',
  sheet='table#',action='CreateWorksheet')".

Export all custom tables to separate files named extest1,xls, extest2, ...
SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT TABLES 
/IF SUBTYPE="'Custom Table'" PROCESS=ALL
/CUSTOM FUNCTION="customoutputfunctions.excelexport(file='c:/temp/extest#.xls')

You can install this command from the Utilities menu in Statistics 22-23 or the Extensions menu in V24.  The installation includes the customoutputfunctions.py module, but if you have an old version of SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT, you might need to update it.  The excelexport function was added in 2/2013.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped me